# Why Mysql command line import slower than PhpMyAdmin

Tags: import, mysql

I've a mysql dump file, it's size 3.6 MB . First i've tried import it to my remote server with this terminal command

```
mysql -hHOST -uUSER -p DBNAME < /path/of/backup.sql
```

It took about 30 minutes (really) .

And then i've tried importing same file via PhpMyAdmin on my remote server, and it took about *1.5 MINUTES* . Can you tell me why `mysql` command is really so slow than PhpMyAdmin. They both uplaoding 3.6 MB file and then executing same amount of SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local mysql cli client does not transfer a file of 3.6MB. Instead it transfers every single query inside the file separately. This leads to a much higher network latency, depending on network connection and server setup. It's the difference between streaming a single block of binary data and thousands of blocks adding up to the same volume.

Comment: So mysql cli parsing dump file to single queries and sending them to server one by one ?

Comment: The mysql client runs _queries_ against a database server, not files. It is impossible to feed a file into a mysql database server. `phpmysqladmin` does the same, but it does it locally, on the server side, thus it can act much faster in this specific situation since it does not experience any network latency once it received the file.

Comment: You might want to try to transfer the file using ssh and feed it into a server side local cli mysql client. That will probably beat the phpmyadmin application.

Answer (score 1):

It is network related problem, just move your file on mysql server and then import locally, it should take hardly 10 to 15 seconds:

```
mysql -uroot -p dbname < /root/backup.sql
```

Comment: i've tried 5 times. Also i've tried from a different web server (its' uplaod speed is really good) but nothing changed. It took about 30 minutes, every time. Also if it's network related problem, how can it upload to server at 1.5 minutes?